# Showing a result based on selected images

Tags: android

I am currently developing an android app which enables user to select the several images based upon which a particular set of texts displays as a result on final,Do I need to develop database?

Comment: Please give more details to your problem, and please fix your language errors.

Comment: Need a clearer problem definition; if the images are related to some sort of text, then yes, you need some way of matching them.